# Model variable bool from html radiobutton

Tags: c#, .net, razor-pages

I'm new to .NET Core 5 and I've got a question.

Is it possible to somehow connect html input (for example from radio bootstrap input) with bool variable in Razor pages model? And also, how can I "print" variable on website? Because this way #Model.Logical doesn't work.

Example:
C# Class Model

```
public class Logical
{
    public string logicalAtrr { get; set; }
}
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public class logicalModel : PageModel
{
    public Logical logical { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
```

cshtml

```
@page
@model ...
@{}

<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1" asp-for="logical.logicalAtrr" value="true">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
        True/False
    </label>

    <p>@Model.logical</p>
</div>
```

I'm really sorry if that question is wrong but I try to figure this Razor Pages concept and Web Development from scratch

Also, when I try to give [BindProperty] above the Logical class I've got an error:

*Error  CS0592  Attribute 'BindProperty' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations.*

I'm really be very thankful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a checkbox for a simple true/false option. If you use radios, you need to provide two - one for each state. You cannot deselect a single radio.

The checkbox should be bound to a Boolean property. Model  binding will take care of ensuring the the correct value is assigned on the server.

```
public class Logical
{
    public bool LogicalAttr { get; set; }
}
```

There is no need to set `name`, `id` or `value` attributes on input tag helpers. Razor Pages takes care of that. Just assign the property to the `asp-for` attribute:

```
<input asp-for="Logical.LogicalAttr" class="form-check-input" />
```

The `BindProperty` attribute should be assigned to the public PageModel property declaration:

```
public class LogicalModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Logical Logical { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
```

It cannot be applied to the class, so this won't work and will raise the compiler error you referred to:

```
[BindProperty]
public class Logical
{
   ...
```

More reading here (my site, btw):
Checkboxes: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes
Radios: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/radios
Model Binding: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Comment: Yes, your site is great! Bakery tutorial is probably the best which I've found! Thank you very much for your job! 

But, sorry for asking, but I really don't understand why, when I add a [BindProperty] I've got this error msg?

Error CS0592 Attribute 'BindProperty' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations.

Could you maybe give me a short explanation or further references? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't apply the `BindProperty` attribute to a class. You apply it to PageModel property declarations instead. I've updated the answer to add clarity.